# Java Average Program

Tags: java, average

Write a class called Average that can be used to calculate average of several integers. It should contain the following methods:

1. A method that accepts two integer parameters and returns their average.
2. A method that accepts three integer parameters and returns their average.
3. A method that accepts two integer parameters that represent a range.

Issue an error message and return zero if the second parameter is less than the first one. Otherwise, the method should return the average of the integers in that range (inclusive).
Implement the class and write a program to test its methods and submit your source code (.java files).

I am stuck on part three, I don't even really understand the stipulation. Will I be using a floating point / double? Here is the program I have thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numb1, numb2, numb3, userInput;
    System.out.println("Enter '2' if you wish to average two numbers enter '3' if you wish to average 3.");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (userInput == 2){
      System.out.println("Enter two numbers you'd like to be averaged.");
      numb1 = keyboard.nextInt();
      numb2 = keyboard.nextInt();
      Average ave = new Average();
      System.out.println("The average is: " + ave.average(numb1, numb2));
      System.exit(1);
    }
    if(userInput == 3){
      System.out.println("Enter three numbers you'd like to be averaged.");
      numb1 = keyboard.nextInt();
      numb2 = keyboard.nextInt();
      numb3 = keyboard.nextInt();
      Average ave = new Average();
      System.out.println("The average is: " + ave.average(numb1, numb2, numb3));
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
  public static int average (int num1, int num2) {
    return (num1 + num2) / 2;
  } 
  public static int average (int numb1, int numb2, int numb3){ 
    return (numb1 + numb2 + numb3) / 3; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you do homework yourself?

Comment: I was just asking for guidance on part three and I've been trying to write this program for about an hour so how about you stop wasting my time and keep your smart remarks to yourself? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the answers of your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507108/java-averaging-program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really here to do your homework, but since I'm already here, the range is the difference between the largest and smallest number.

```
public int returnRange(int first, int second) {
    if(first > second)
        return first-second;
    else
        return second-first;
}
```

To make things easier though...

```
public double returnAverage(int...numbers) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
        total += numbers;
    }

    return total/numbers.length();
}

public int returnRange(int...numbers) {
    int holder = 0;

    int highest;
    int lowest;

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
        if(numbers[i] > holder) {
            holder = numbers[i];
    }
    highest = holder;

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
        if(numbers[i] < holder) {
            holder = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    lowest = holder;

    return highest-lowest;
}
```

Last 2 methods are un-tested, but from experience, should work fine. These methods have arrays for the parameters, so you can do as many numbers as you'd like.

Comment: What is the result if I call `returnAverage(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2)` ?

Comment: @Vitkinov It'll overflow at first (max + max). When an integer reaches it's max, and you add onto it, it resets to minimum value, then continues adding from there. If you're really curious for the answer, test it out. If you're wondering how to avoid overflows, use a different datatype (`long` can go up to 9 tril, and `[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)` has no limit, but its not a primitive)

Answer (score 1):

Please don't re-ask the same question as you just asked here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507108/java-averaging-program`

Rather update your other post to reflect your new code / questions.

Now onto your question:

1. A method that accepts two integer parameters that represent a range. Issue an error message and return zero if the second parameter is less than the first one. Otherwise, the method should return the average of the integers in that range (inclusive). Implement the class and write a program to test its methods and submit your source code (.java files).

Lets start by declaring our method and we'll declare it as static to conform to your program (since you're not creating your own objects). Then we want to check if the parameters follow the assignment instructions and return values accordingly.

```
public static int getRange(int firstValue, int secondValue)
    {
        int range;
        if (firstValue > secondValue)
            range = firstValue - secondValue;
        else
        {
            range = 0;
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
        return range;
    }
```

**To promote your understanding it's up to you to find the average of the integers in the range!

Answer (score 0):

> the method should return the average of the integers in that range (inclusive).

You're asked to return the average of all integers in the range bounded by the two parameters.

For example, if parameters were 5 and 10, the method should return the average of 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10, which is 7.5. (5 and 10 are included because the question says the range should be "inclusive".)

To find the average, use a for loop to sum each integer in the range, then divide by the number of integers.

> Will I be using a floating point / double?

The return value should be a `float` or `double`, since the average isn't always a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method check for -1 and return error when first value is greater than second

```
public double avgRange(int a, int b){

    if(a>b){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        double total=0;
        for(int x=a; x<=b; x++){
            total = total + x;
        }
        return total/(b-a+1);
    }
}
```